# Taking pictures with Titanium.Media.showCamera causing application data size to grow even though images are saved outside data directory

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am saving images outside of the `applicationDataDirectory` so the user can browse for them using the file system.  However, the data size of the application continues to grow with each photo taken.  Even if the photos are removed from the external directory, the space is still occupied.

Do images get stored in the `applicationDataDirectory` regardless of code below?

```
Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        showControls : true,
        autorotate : false,
        saveToPhotoGallery : false,
        success : function(event) {
            var image = event.media;
            var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile('file:///sdcard/images/', filename);
            file.write(image);
            console.log("Got image from camera & saved it");
```

Comment: It looks like you might have found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Ticket opened: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3717